# Override a linked curve in blender

Tags: bezier-curves, shape-keys

I might have found a limitation of blender but just to be sure I would like to ask the community if its possible to override a linked curve in a scene.

Scenario: I have a curve that I want to duplicate 4 times and attach to an armiture that has 4 bones.

The curves have shape keys that are activated by the position of each bone.

The shapekeys are linear and i want to add a driver to the evaluation value so when the bones in the armiture change position they drive the shapekey value.

I would like it so the curves shapekey evaluation values are independant of eachother but still linked to the main curve so if i want to edit the shape keys they are updated on all the curves.

Is this possible?